# Javascript If/Else paradox setting value while scrolling

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to set a value while scrolling if something is true.  The problem is that I am looping through several elements and if it is true in one element it will be false in the other.  So true will never be set unless it is true in the last element in the loop.

So I am checking the progress of the element from a start point to a finish point.  If the progress is greater than 0 and less than 1 I want to set the paused value to true else set it to false.  But the next element in the loop overwrites that.

```
const updateSections = () => {
  queues.forEach(s => {
    const { el, start, diff } = s;
    const progress = getProgress(start, diff);
    paused = progress > 0 && progress < 1 ? true : false;
  });
};
```

Here is a very simplified version of what I am talking about:

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/m6q2dyes/)

```js
const display = document.querySelector('.display span');
let yScroll = window.scrollY;
let sectionNodes = document.querySelectorAll('.xSection');
let queues = [];
let paused = false;

const updateSections = () => {
  queues.forEach(s => {
    const { el, start, diff } = s;
    const progress = getProgress(start, diff);
    paused = progress > 0 && progress < 1 ? true : false;
  });
  display.innerHTML = paused ? 'True' : 'False';
};

const createQueue = element => {
  const el = getElementData(element);
  const start = el.offsetTop;
  const end = start + el.rect.height;
  const diff = end - start;
  queues.push( {
    el,
    start,
    end,
    diff
  });
}

const getElementData = el => {
  if (!el) return null;
  const node = el;
  const parent = el.parentNode;
  const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  const parentRect = parent.getBoundingClientRect();
  const offsetTop = rect.top + scrollY;
  return {
    node,
    parent,
    rect,
    parentRect,
    offsetTop
  };
};

const getProgress = (start, diff) => {
  return Math.min(1, Math.max(0, ((yScroll - start) / diff).toFixed(6)));
};

const updateScroll = () => {
  yScroll = window.scrollY;
  updateSections();
};

window.addEventListener('scroll', updateScroll, false);

sectionNodes.forEach(n => createQueue(n));
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.xSection {
  position: relative;
  width: 130vw;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.xSection .content {
  background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.display{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background: green;
  z-index: 5;
}

footer {
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="display">Value: <span>False</span></div>
<h1>Scroll Down</h1>
<div style="height: 100vh"></div>
<div class="xSection">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="xSection">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div style="height: 100vh"></div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

So in the above snippet true should be set when each of the sections hits the top and scrolls the height of the element.  But true is only set when the last one hits the top because the value is overwritten by the next element in the loop.

Is there a good technique to set true when the current element is in the progress zone and remove it when it is not without it being overwritten by the next element?

Comment: Is the progress zone you're talking about the visible part of the scrolling area?

Comment: @nixkuroi The progress zone in this case is when the element hits the top to the elements height but in my actual code it can be vastly different.  But it will be from the start to end values I am tracking the progress from those values.

Answer (score 0):

Generally what you should do is set `paused` to `false` outside the `.forEach`, and then in the loop set it based on the current value:

```
const updateSections = () => {
  paused = false;
  queues.forEach(s => {
    const { el, start, diff } = s;
    const progress = getProgress(start, diff);
    paused = paused || progress > 0 && progress < 1;
  });
  display.innerHTML = paused ? 'True' : 'False';
};
```

That way if it's already paused, it'll stay paused even if subsequent queues are still in progress.

Note that you *never* need anything of the form `booleanTest ? true : false` as the test itself already returns `true` or `false`. If you want a boolean value from a test based on JavaScript "truthiness", you can use `!!nonBooleanTest`.